# get or detect an ajax request is executing by url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have many called ajax request from many js file. I want to detect few ajax request to interrupt the execution and execute a newer one.
can I detect and stop the ajax with their url?

I would be greatly appreciative of any help I could gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery). It's untested, but should give the idea. It stuffs the xhr call into an array, along with URL, and then calls them back out to kill them based on URL.

```
var url = "some.php",
   xhr_global = [];

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

xhr_global.push({xhr: jqxhr, url: url});

function kill_url(url_pick){

    for(var i=0; i<xhr_global.length; i++){
        if (xhr_global[i].url == url_pick)     // If url matches, kill xhr
            xhr_global[i].xhr.abort();
    }

}

kill_url("some.php");     // Call function to kill the xhrs
```

Note that, as the post says, this kills the process on client-side, but not server-side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is if I have an access to the declaration of the ajax. But if I have not access to his declaration and have just the url, how can I do it

Comment: If you don't have access to the declaration of the ajax (eg., you can't save the jqxhr 'promise'), then I don't believe you can stop the ajax call.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it is very helpful but I have to abort an ajax called by my pc and I can't access to the code.